# Problems with loading data from API - want to use async/await instead

Tags: angular, api, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

From my component I'm calling on the method in the service which gets me a order from the API.

My service:

```
 getOrder(orderId: number): Observable<Order> {
 const url = `${this.ordersUrl}/getOrder?orderId=${orderId}&country=${Cookie.get('country')}`;
 return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).map(response => response.json()).catch(this.errorService.handleError);
```

}

My component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.orderId = +params['orderId'];
  this.orderService.getOrder(this.orderId)
  .subscribe( order => {
    this.order = order;
    console.log(this.order.commentAdmin);},
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
});
```

When I load my template for my component with the data I get from "order" I get that the data is undefined. But if I console.log it, I get the correct response.
I'm thinking that it loads the data before it loads the template and there is something that goes wrong there. I want to try and use async and await to get and show the data but I'm not sure how to do this. We've solved this problem by using delays since none of us have used Angular before. How can I do this correctly by using await and async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an elvis operator in your template to handle `order` being undefined.

```
<p>{{ order?.commentAdmin }}<p>
```

the reason this is happening is that angular is binding the `order` object before data has been returned from the endpoint and is breaking the templating.

Comment: Thank you, this did remove all the warnings in the console. So by doing this it waits to bind the data until the data has been returned from the endpoint?

Comment: The elvis operator is syntactic sugar for a ternary null check. it's the same as `{{ order ? order.commentAdmin : '' }}`. you can chain them together `order?.commentAdmin?.userID` or even use them with the `async` pipe `(order | async)?.commentAdmin`

Comment: Np glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go a more reactive approach and make use of the observable you are getting back from your service.

Change your component to something like this:

```
order$: Observable<Order>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.order$ = this.route.params
    .switchMap(params => this.orderService.getOrder(+params['orderId']))
    .catch(error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

And your template to:

```
<div *ngIf="order$ | async as order">
{{ order.commentAdmin }}
</div>
```

Advantage your don't have to unsubscribe as Angular does it for your with async and it only renders order data when the observable has emitted a value.

Comment: I get:
 
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoiceId' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoiceId' of undefined

This is for other properties that the order model has. Do I need to do anything to the method in the service with which I retrieve the data with?

Comment: I think your service is fine. Everywhere in your template you now need to change your code to read from the Observable with async. It looks like you are accessing order and not the Observable.